# Mapping the value of a json array using filter and groupby

Tags: ecmascript-6, angular5, lodash

My json is like below. I am trying to group my objects based on the role id for  target id equal to 1083.

My json:

```
[  {
    "id" :1,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
  },
    {
    "id" :2,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
  },
    {
    "id" :3,
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1084",
    }
  },
  {
    "id" :4,
    "role": {
      "id": "3",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
  }
  ]
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "25" : [
  {
    "id": 1
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
    },
       { "id": 2
    "role": {
      "id": "25",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
    "id" :4,
    "role": {
      "id": "3",
    },
    "target": {
      "id": "1083",
    }
  }]
}
```

So for my result json, it's grouped by 25 and 3. The third record doesn't exist in my expected result as it's target id is 1084

I tried filter to get only target id 1083, but when I tried to use grouby, I am getting errors

```
data.filter(o => { 
          return o.target.id === "1083"
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lodash via [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) and [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy):

```js
var data = [{ "id": 1, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } }, { "id": 2, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } }, { "id": 3, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1084", } }, { "id": 4, "role": { "id": "3", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } } ]

const groupIt = (targetId) => _.chain(data)
   .filter(x => x.target.id ===targetId)
   .groupBy('role.id')
   .value()

console.log(groupIt('1083'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could achieve the same without lodash via [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{ "id": 1, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } }, { "id": 2, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } }, { "id": 3, "role": { "id": "25", }, "target": { "id": "1084", } }, { "id": 4, "role": { "id": "3", }, "target": { "id": "1083", } } ]

const groupIt = (targetId) => data.filter(x => x.target.id === targetId)
   .reduce((r, c) => (r[c.role.id] = [...r[c.role.id] || [], c], r), {})

console.log(groupIt('1083'))
```

Comment: When I tried the first solution, I am getting cannot find name '_'.

Comment: Must be a lodash version dependency issue. See now I changed to not use the shorthand for chaining with just `_.chain`

Comment: Yes. sorry for the delay

Comment: Just wondering is there a way I can use sort also along with it, so that I can get the elements sorted by id. I am currently using chain, filter, groupBy